# How to wait for the last callback in a series of callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node's express to expose a computation library via REST api.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  performComputation(data,function(result){
     res.send(result);
  };
}
```

I cannot change the interface or any internal of the lib being used. The problem is, that the library calls the result callback multiple times. For each call a new computation result is added to `result`. The first time the callback is called it may contain `[1]`, second `[1,91]`, third `[1,91,31]` and so on.

I don't know in advance how many times the callback will be called. What needs to be send via `req.send()` is only the `result` submitted within the last callback performed. This result does already contain all the values that were published in the previous callbacks.

So how to "wait" for the last callback or achieve this in another way?

Comment: If the number of calls is unknown beforehand and the library won't tell you anything about it, and doesn't mark the last call as special, it's totally impossible to identify the last call.

Comment: Impossible to catch it maybe, but isn't there any other possibility of solving this?

Comment: Can't you predict the number of callbacks to expect? Also, why are there multiple callbacks in the first place. Sad to say, but a timer might do.

Comment: such as if(data.length == result.length) ?

Comment: @k_wave No, impossible. Can you tell us more about that library, maybe link its docs? Btw, I would consider this kind of behaviour a major bug - nothing that you have to change in the interface, but something that the library author needs to *fix*.

Answer (score 0):

I would create custom middleware to do what you need to do before sending the response, then just rely on that custom middleware to actually send the response.

Ex:

```
var myCustomMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  //do what you need to do
  //send res.
}

//setup your app
app.use(routes)
app.use(myCustomMiddleware)
```

Comment: How does this at all answer the question?

Comment: because if you just alter the response in your controllers and use the custom middleware at the end then you could get the response after it is handled by the controller. This would ensure that the middleware is the last function to alter/see the response in any way, ie finished with callbacks

Comment: But that just moves the problem to the "middleware", but doesn't solve it.

Comment: I don't think I'm following the question. k_wave has the value after all the callbacks are finished, using the middleware at the end would ensure that all the callbacks are finished, thus it should be fine to send the value.

Comment: Don't you have to run `next()`? I don't think the middleware can automatically assume when it ends, rather you have to specify it using `next()` which is puzzling OP since he doesn't know when the callbacks will stop. My advice, OP? Hack that stupid library, make sure it doesn't have some stupid for-loop that does `callback(data)`.

Comment: if you were to do something like `res.send.end` then it should end it right there

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many times the callback is going to get called then you have to guess - either use some number that you think is enough, or use some time to wait for it.

But unless you know how often the callbacks are called or something like that then you will not be able to tell for sure when is the last time of the callback getting called.

Example with a number of data elements:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  performComputation(data,function(result){
     if (result.length === 10) {
         res.send(result);
     }
  });
});
```

example with waiting a specific delay:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  let data = [];
  performComputation(data,function(result){
     let data = result;
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
     res.send(data);
  }, 1000);
});
```

A more advanced way would be to see if there was enough time after the last time the callback got called and only then send the answer etc. There are many ways to do it.

Of course the problem here is that even though it prevents the response to be sent multiple times, it doesn't prevent the callbacks to being fired in the future, possibly taking up the system resources.

Streams would be a better pattern to use for cases like this but since you cannot change the function that callas the callbacks then you have to use one of the workarounds like those above.